# xcodebuild error: action 'archive' is not implemented

Tags: ios, xcodebuild

```
xcodebuild archive -archivePath ${archive_path} -workspace ${workspace_path} -scheme ${scheme} -configuration ${configuration} -sdk iphoneos
```

> warning: unhandled ProductType key IsUnitTest
>   warning: unhandled ProductType key IsUITest
>   warning: unhandled ProductType key IsUnitTest
>   warning: unhandled ProductType key IsUnitTest
>   warning: unhandled ProductType key IsUITest
>   warning: unhandled ProductType key IsUnitTest
>   error: cannot find base BuildSystem specification 'embedded-shared:com.apple.buildsettings.standard'
>   error: cannot find base ProductType specification 'embedded-shared:com.apple.product-type.framework'
>   error: cannot find base ProductType specification 'embedded-shared:com.apple.product-type.xpc-service'
>   error: cannot find base ProductType specification 'embedded:com.apple.product-type.pluginkit-plugin'
>   error: cannot find base BuildSystem specification 'embedded:com.apple.build-system.core'
>   error: cannot find base BuildSystem specification 'embedded:com.apple.build-system.native'
>   error: cannot find base Linker specification 'embedded:com.apple.pbx.linkers.ld'
>   error: cannot find base ProductType specification 'embedded-simulator:com.apple.product-type.pluginkit-plugin'
>   error: action 'archive' is not implemented
>   warning: export archive not implemented
>   E, [2017-04-12T17:52:04.100088 #11625] ERROR -- : File does not exist

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Seems like your Xcode / Command Line Tools / Developer Tools aren't correctly set up. Please post the contents of `xcode-select -p` and `sw_vers -productVersion`

Comment: `xcode-select -p`: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer.
`sw_vers -productVersion`:10.12.4